# convert .WAR for auto deploy in karaf/servicemix

Tags: servlets, osgi, war, apache-servicemix, hotdeploy

I've got very simple .WAR containing example servlet. I'm able to deploy it in servicemix using the following command:

`osgi:install file:///home/seiho/apache-servicemix-4.4.2/deploy/TestServlet.war?Bundle-SymbolicName=TestServlet&Webapp-Context=/TestServlet`

And then see it in my browser. But only with full path to a file, e.g.: localhost:8080/TestServlet/index.html or localhost:8080/TestServlet/TestServlet (my servlet is TestServlet class). 

I'd like to launch the index.html page automatically after entering: localhost:8080/TestServlet

how to do it?

MORE IMPORTANT
I need a way to convert the .WAR file or servlet project (I've got the sources) so that new .WAR file can be auto-deployed by copying it to $SERVICEMIX_HOME/deploy directory.

I've tried editing the MANIFEST.MF file, but with no success. Probably I'm doing something wrong.

Thanks for any advice/help.

Comment: What does your new manifest look like?

Comment: Manifest-Version: 1.0
Ant-Version: Apache Ant 1.8.3
Created-By: 1.7.0_06-b24 (Oracle Corporation)
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Bundle-SymbolicName: TestServlet
Bundle-ClassPath: ., WEB-INF/classes
Import-Package: javax.servlet, javax.servlet.http

Comment: http://n900crack.yoyo.pl/images/TestServlet.war - is a link to the .WAR file I've got.

Answer (score 0):

To be recognised as a wab, you need to add a context path header to your manifest:

```
Web-ContextPath: TestServlet
```

Comment: Yes, I did that. But still it couldn't auto-deploy. Adding the bundle version fixed auto-deployment problem. Next, I add Web-ContextPath: TestServlet entry, just like you wrote it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's working now! I was doing my MANIFEST.MF according to this page: http://team.ops4j.org/wiki/display/ops4j/Pax+Web+Extender+-+War+-+OSGi-fy

The problem was that for some reason "Bundle-Version: 1.0" line was required as opposed to optional as stated on that page.

Honestly, just adding the Bundle-Version fix-it.

I knew it was something wrong with the MANIFEST.MF and after Holly Cummins' question I played with it a bit more. Thanks Holly.

I still can't do anything with the manual site launching (have to manually enter the index.html).

`http://localhost:8080/TestServlet/` gives me this:

---

HTTP ERROR 404

Problem accessing /TestServlet/. Reason:

```
Not Found
```

Powered by Jetty://

---

`http://localhost:8080/TestServlet/index.html` gives me proper site.